Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classesShiroWebFilterConfiguration and FilterRegistrationBean
I'm having trouble running my Springboot Maven application. The problem started with a missing dependency which let to another issue i cant get fixed, i have tried multiple suggestions from throughout the web to no avail. I did remove the .m2 folder and did a fresh build but the same error comes back.
The error in my console:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.apache.shiro.spring.config.web.autoconfigure.ShiroWebFilterConfiguration.filterShiroFilterRegistrationBean(ShiroWebFilterConfiguration.java:63)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(javax.servlet.DispatcherType, javax.servlet.DispatcherType[])'

The calling method's class, org.apache.shiro.spring.config.web.autoconfigure.ShiroWebFilterConfiguration, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/apache/shiro/shiro-spring-boot-starter/2.0.1/shiro-spring-boot-starter-2.0.1.jar!/org/apache/shiro/spring/config/web/autoconfigure/ShiroWebFilterConfiguration.class

The called method's class, org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar!/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/FilterRegistrationBean.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean: file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.AbstractFilterRegistrationBean: file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.DynamicRegistrationBean: file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean: file:/E:/Mysoftware/apache-maven-3.9.5/repo/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.3.1/spring-boot-3.3.1.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.apache.shiro.spring.config.web.autoconfigure.ShiroWebFilterConfiguration and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean


Process finished with exit code 1


My pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shiro_springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shiro_springboot</name>
    <description>shiro_springboot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-spring-boot3-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-generator</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
            <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


Any input is welcome.

SpringBoot version is not compatible with Shiro'version
In class(org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean), the method  setDispatcherTypes(javax.servlet.DispatcherType, javax.servlet.DispatcherType[]) does not exist in SpringBoot, But Shiro need it.
You need to downgrade or upgrade version of SpringBoot/Shiro.
